# How to place the caption of a lstlisting in the margin? (scrreprt, floatrow)

Tags: floats, listings, captions, floatrow

In the following mwe I am using the `floatrow` package to place the figure captions in the margin.

How can I do the same for `listings`?

**Update:**

Some listings are spread over two pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!10}}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain, font={small, it}, labelfont={bf}}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{
    margins=hangright,
    capposition=beside,
    capbesideposition={top,right},
    floatwidth=\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\chapter{How to place the caption of a lstlisting in the margin?}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Greybox with an 'A' in the center}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\todo[]{TODO: Place the caption of the following listing in the margin.}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\lstinline{main()} function}]
int main(void)
{
    while (true) {
        /* loop forever */
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}%

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: floatrow mwe]

Comment: How about surrounding `listings` inside a `figure` environment? I am not sure what could go wrong (e.g. how about page break?) but visually, it seems it does what you want...

Comment: How about put a `figure` *before* the `lstlisting`. Then page-breaking is fine.

Comment: I have tried to put the `listing` in a `figure[H]` environment. Result: the caption is placed in the margin. But page-breaking does not work for listings -- I would like to have the code splitted between pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you `\usepackage{caption}` because `\hangindent` is not zero. It is `scrreprt` aligning margin paragraphs with `:`.But since `caption` conflicts with my code <del>I am not going to use it</del> I updated my answer with new approaches.

- Declare a new float type `mylst`. So now you can use `floatrow` to format captions.
- Redefine `\lst@makecaption` so that `listings` will not typeset captions anymore. Instead, I pass the caption-text to a `mylst`. (In other words, I want to put a `mylst` before your C-code. But I cannot do that until `lstlisting` read your caption-text.)
- Take care of `\hangindent` and spacing. (Beware that `\vskip-1\baselineskip` and `\vskip-2\baselineskip` are magic numbers. The spacing is `\documentclass`-dependent.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=2cm,right=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow}
    \DeclareNewFloatType{mylst}{placement=h!,name=Mylst,fileext=lom}
    \floatsetup{margins=hangright,floatwidth=\textwidth,capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top,right}}

\begin{document}
    \listof{mylst}{List of Mylst}
    \hrule
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \caption{usual figure caption}
        so sad you cannot see the figure.
    \end{figure}
    \hrule
    \begin{lstlisting}
        \This#is$the&usual^lstlisting_.
    \end{lstlisting}
    \hrule
    \makeatletter
    \def\lst@makecaption#1#2{
        \vskip-1\baselineskip\begin{mylst}%
            \caption[\lst@@caption]{\hangindent0pt\lst@caption\vspace*{-\paperheight}}%
            \hrule width\textwidth height0pt%some how I need something width enough here
        \end{mylst}\vskip-2\baselineskip}%
    \makeatother
    \hrule
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={[short caption for .lom]Although I cancel the hanindent this caption is still too long so please make sure your lstlisting code (or some remark you write after it or whatever) is long enough so that the next marginpar will not be overlapped.}]
        \This#is$the&new^lstlisting_.
    \end{lstlisting}
    \hrule

    What next?
\end{document}
```

### UPDATE

If `caption` is loaded, there are still two ways to go:

- The main problem is that the caption-box is defined as `\parbox[b]{#1}{#2}` with no reason, so redefined it as `\parbox[t]{#1}{#2}`.
- Or, instead of making caption-box of zero height, we can make `mylst` very very tall and attach to it an appropriate negative skip.

---

- By the way there are some issues about `@` breaking List of Mylst. So in the following code `\let\lstatatcaption\lst@@caption` is necessary.
- Spacing is still a mess.
- After all, a caption-box will exceed the bottom edge if it is too long. Leave a comment if you need a more sophisticated one and tell me what kind of behavior you expect.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=2cm,right=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{format=plain,font={small,it},labelfont={bf},belowskip=-10cm}
\usepackage{floatrow}
    \DeclareNewFloatType{mylst}{placement=H,name=Mylst,fileext=lom}
    \floatsetup{margins=hangright,floatwidth=\textwidth,capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top,right}}

\begin{document}
    \listof{mylst}{List of Mylst}
    \hrule
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \caption{usual figure caption}
        so sad you cannot see the figure.
    \end{figure}
    \hrule
    \begin{lstlisting}
        \This#is$the&usual^lstlisting_.
    \end{lstlisting}
    \hrule
\begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \def\caption@parbox#1#2{\parbox[t]{#1}{#2}}
    \def\lst@makecaption#1#2{
        \begin{mylst}
            \let\lstatatcaption\lst@@caption
            \caption[\lstatatcaption]{\lst@caption\vspace*{-\paperheight}}
            \hrule width\textwidth height0pt
        \end{mylst}}
    \hrule
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={[short caption for .lom]Although I cancel the hangindent this caption is still too long so please make sure your lstlisting code (or some remark you write after it or whatever) is long enough so that the next marginpar will not be overlapped.}]
        \This#is$even&newer^lstlisting_.
    \end{lstlisting}
\endgroup
    \hrule
    \vspace*{18cm}
    \hrule
\begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \def\lst@makecaption#1#2{
        \begin{mylst}
            \let\lstatatcaption\lst@@caption
            \caption[\lstatatcaption]{\lst@caption}
            \vrule width0ptheight\paperheight
        \end{mylst}
        \vspace*{-\paperheight}}
    \hrule
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={[another short caption for .lom]This time caption package cancels the hangindent and mylst, being very very tall, follows immediately a negative skip which makes everything fine as before.}]
        \This#is$the&new^lstlisting_.
    \end{lstlisting}
\endgroup
    \hrule
    What next?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any chance to get it to work with the `caption` package?

Comment: @sergej you can try to replace `\vspace*{-\paperheight}` by other lengths such as `\vspace*{-1cm}` with `caption` loaded. Then you will see the problem bothering me.

Comment: Can we replace `\vskip-2\baselineskip` by `the height of the caption box * -1`?

Comment: Here is the point: `\caption@parbox#1#2` is defined as `\parbox[b]{#1}{#2}` for no reason. Add `\def\caption@parbox#1#2{\parbox[t]{#1}{#2}}` fix this problem. But spacing is still a mess...

Comment: @sergej I updated my answer.

Comment: As you can seen [here](https://www.writelatex.com/1460113nkjmkn) the caption is not vertically aligned with the listing (the caption is too high). Can this be solved?

Comment: In the definition of `\lst@makecaption` you can insert some `\vspace{-.123456789cm}` before or after `mylst`. As I said before the spacing depends on `\documentclass`, `listings`, `caption`, and `floatrow`. In general I have no idea how to give the exact number.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, I was hoping for a less complicated approach.